# Maximizing the variance of projected data

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, linear-regression, principal-component-analysis

[image]

Show that this expression can be written as:

[image]

I have tried multiple approaches like going through a backward proof by taking individual norms and trying to reconstruct but I am unable to find a clue. Looking forward to some hints so that I can start in that direction.

Comment: Can you show that $$\|Px\|^2_2+\|(I-P)x\|^2_2=\|x\|^2_2?$$

Comment: I can try but looks like it will not help much as what would I do ∥(I−P)x∥22 this

Comment: Note $(I-P)x=x-Px$